# Does df mean a differential or gradient?

Tags: differential-geometry

In [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient) and also how I had originally learned, $df$ is said to be the differential of a scalar function $f$ and is a linear map from $R^n \to R$. However, in this lecture prof. Frederic Schuller mentions that the gradient of $f$ is defined as a linear map from $T_p M \to R$ (see 1:27:08 of [this video](https://youtu.be/pepU_7NJSGM?t=5216)). So, what really is df?

Comment: As you may have realized the notation for differentation/differentials is rather loose and it changes from book to book and from author to author. Maybe French authors use $df$ for the gradient, English and Russian authors use $\nabla f$ and $\mathrm{grad}f$

Comment: Oh jeez @LordCommander Thanks though, that makes me a feel a bit more sane

Comment: @LordCommander never heard a French prof. call $df$ the gradient, but if that is true, I apologize on behalf of French mathematicians

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is so confusing.

What Prof. Frederic Schuller called a gradient of $f$ in the video is exactly what (most?) others called the differential $df$ of $f$, or the total derivative of $f$ (this is the notation used in the wikipedia page).

He makes it very very clear that the "gradient" of $f$ he defined

- is a $(0,1)$-tensor, a covector,
- is not a vector.

while the more common terminology (in differential geometry) is that the gradient of $f$ is a vector, and is defined when you have a Riemannian metric. This is discussed also in the same wiki page.